# netezza how to reorder table after data has been loaded

Tags: netezza

my table in netezza looks something like this:

```
b,2
b,1
a,2
a,1
a,3
c,1
c,2
```

I want to reorder it by the first coloumn so it looks like this:

```
a,2
a,1
a,3
b,2
b,1
c,1
c,2
```

How do i reorder the table without creating a new one?

Comment: What end result do you want to achieve by ordering the table?

Comment: i just want to make sure the table is optimised. my understanding that zone maps are automatically added given the sorting.. so i want the table sorted properly so these are optimised.

Comment: Ah, ok. Added an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optimize zone maps for a particular column without recreating the table with an ORDER BY, alter the table to have an ORGANIZE ON ( COL_NAME ) clause. This won't immediately cause any changes in the table on disk, but sets the stage for GROOM to cluster the data.

After that, run GROOM TABLE TABLE_NAME RECORDS ALL. This will cluster the data on that column.

Subsequently run a GROOM TABLE TABLE_NAME RECORDS READY to cluster newly added rows.

I should also add that only INTEGER, DATE, and TIMESTAMP will be tracked by zone maps by default, but using ORGANIZE will cause zone maps to be tracked for character columns.

Answer (score -2):

you can use one of the following sorting algorithms with space complexity of O(1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

you'll have to adopt the algorithm to match letters instead of numerals but that's pretty easy.

Comment: seems like an overly complex response - all I want to do is ORDER BY column 1?

Comment: I thought this question was general and referred to constant space complexity ordering, as i got to see it through the 'order' tag which is theoretical stuff.